# Change first row of a column if it meets a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a very basic problem. I have searched SO, but I didn't find the answer.

My DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
       'a': [10, 50, 3],
       'b': [5, 4, 5],
    }
)
```

Now I want to change `df.b.iloc[0]` to 1 if `df.a.iloc[0]` is greater than 5.

Expected output:

```
    a    b
0  10    1
1  50    4
2   3    5
```

Attempts:

```
# attempt 1
df[df.a > 5].iloc[0]
# attempt 2
df.loc[df.a.iloc[0] > 5, 'b'] = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `if`

```
if df.loc[0, 'a'] > 5:
    df.loc[0, 'b'] = 1
```

df

```
    a   b
0   10  1
1   50  4
2   3   5
```

---

if you don want `if` and inplace df, use following code

```
cond1 = df.loc[0, 'a'] > 5
cond2 = df.index == 0
out = df.assign(b=df['b'].mask(cond1 & cond2, 1))
```

out

```
    a   b
0   10  1
1   50  4
2   3   5
```